# view all products in un click JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The goal is to create a 'View all' button under the product sheets which, when clicked, adds clones of the latter at the bottom of the page, filling all available spaces.
--> when i click a button "view all", i want to see all the list of the products in alphabetical order.
Can you help me to move on!!
https://jsfiddle.net/oj20rwk3/

```js
ABC.plp = {
    _autoload: [
        "viewAll"
    ],

    viewAll: function() {
        $(".plp-products-container").ready(function() {
            $(".button-row [name=viewALL]").click(function() {
                $(".product-item").show();
           });

           $(".button-row [name=viewALL]").click(function() {
                $(".product-item").hide();
           });
        });
    },
```

Thank you

Comment: Open Developer Tools. What do you see?

Comment: I see all the products because my button don't work now. I need a new function to help me to see some products and when i click a button "view all", i can show all products.

Comment: I see *"ACC is not defined"*. Please read [ask], [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: ACC.plp is my file js and i put all the code in this link https://jsfiddle.net/oj20rwk3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to hide all the product items and then use slice method to show the matching elements. The slice method accepts index (start & end). Read more here - https://api.jquery.com/slice/

```
$( ".product-item" ).hide();
$( ".product-item" ).slice( 6, 10 ).show();
```

To show all product items on click of button you would do the below.

```
$('button[name=viewALL]').click(function(){
   $( ".product-item" ).show();
});
```

To make the button toggle as View All / View Less you would do

```
$('button[name=viewALL]').click(function(){
   let btnText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   if (btnText === 'view all') {
      $(this).text('View Less');
      $( ".product-item" ).show();
   } else if (btnText === 'view less') {
      $(this).text('View All');
      $( ".product-item").not($( ".product-item").slice( 6, 10 )).hide();
   }
});
```

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pdj03sbo/

In the case of sorting in alphabetical order, it is better to sort the data in your controller before you print it in the html.

Comment: I edit my question. Can i apply the same functions for my case?

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to understand the requirement. Its always better to keep the original question as it was and then insert a text 'updated' below the original question and add your new changes

Comment: Yhe question is almost the same, i only added "The goal is to create a 'View all' button under the product sheets which, when clicked, adds clones of the latter at the bottom of the page, filling all available spaces".

Comment: I applied your suggestions and it's work. Thank you for helping. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Glad to know :)

Comment: If we have the case to show other products (replicate the ones we have) when i click view all, how can i use the function append()?

Comment: Can you please raise it as a new question so that we don't confuse SO users with multiple questions & multiple answers for each question in the same post.

Comment: Can you see this link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67079266/view-all-products-with-the-replicate-of-the-list-of-products-presented-in-html-i

Comment: Please can you show this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122787/open-new-tab-only-after-click-popup-modal-button-ok-jquery-js