# view all products with the replicate of the list of products presented in html in un click JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've this code https://jsfiddle.net/oj20rwk3/

The goal is to create a 'View all' button under the product sheets which, when clicked, adds clones of the latter at the bottom of the page, filling all available spaces (in this case replicate the products).
When I click a button "view all", I want to see all products with the replicate of the list of products presented in html in alphabetical order. Can you help me to move on?

```js
ACC.plp = {
    _autoload: [
        ["hideLinkOnSearchBox", $('.js-hide').length > 0],
        "viewAll"
    ],

    hideLinkOnSearchBox: function () {
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();

            if(scroll_top <=1000) {
                 $('.js-hide').removeClass("d-none");
            }
            else if( scroll_top >1000){
                 $('.js-hide').addClass("d-none");
            }
        });
    },

    viewAll: function() {
        $(".plp-products-container").ready(function(){
            $(".button-row [name=viewALL]").click(function(){
                $(".product-item").show();
            });
            $(".button-row [name=viewALL]").click(function(){
                $(".product-item").hide();
            });
        });
    },
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: When clicking 'View All' button you want to clone the available products in the list and append to the bottom of the list? Is that what you meant? or clone the last product from the list and append to the list?

Comment: When clicking 'View All' button i want to clone the available products in the list and append to the bottom of the list --->using the function append(). In the sense of seeing a double product, like: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h when i click view all --> i will see a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a wrapped element for all your `product-item` so that we can easily clone its children with matching `class` name and append to the wrapper.

```
let cloned = false;
$('button[name=viewALL]').click(function(){

  /* Below check is to prevent cloning more than once */

  if (cloned === false ) { 
    cloned = true;
    $(".product-wrapper").children('.product-item').clone().appendTo(".product-wrapper");
  }
});

<div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-item">.A.</div>
    <div class="product-item">.B.</div>
    <div class="product-item">.C.</div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kaop69zg/

Comment: this one is for another question https://jsfiddle.net/azonbj9q/    . I don't want to hide the  some products but I want to see them again when I click the button

Comment: Updated the fiddle. By default all products will be shown & when the user click the button we first check if the products was cloned or not based on 'cloned' flag. If not clone the products and append to the list

Comment: @AyaI Have a look at the updated code and fiddle

Comment: It's work thnks. I've another question that i use modal Boostrap in un form. I want go to home just when i click button "ok" in popup, My problem now is: i get homepage simultaneously with popup. You can look it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122787/open-new-tab-only-after-click-popup-modal-button-ok-jquery-js?noredirect=1#comment118648412_67122787