# Open new tab only after click popup modal button ok jquery js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a form of password and username. I want when I click button "login" (with correct credentials) that it displays a popup that contains a button when the clicks, takes me to the home page of a site

You can find the code here https://jsfiddle.net/hcu0r6dj/1/

```js
login = {
    _autoload: [
 
        "popUpModalLogin"
    ],

 
 popUpModalLogin: function(){
        $(".button-row[name=login]").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.pop-outer').show();

        });
        $(".button-row[name=cancel]").click(function() {
            $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
        });
        $(".button-row[name=ok]").click(function() {
            var href = $(this).data("hrefData");
            if ($.trim(href).length > 0) 
              window.open(href, "page-homepage pageType-ContentPage template-pages-layout-landingLayout2Page pageLabel-homepage"
            );
       
        });


}
    }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap modal?

Comment: Maybe this library will help you to create a Modal Dialog: http://saribe.github.io/eModal/

Comment: Yes. I'm using Boostrap modal

Comment: @AyaI Since you are using button type submit, the page will get refreshed the moment you click login.

Comment: @AyaI Do you plan to use ajax to submit the values to the backend?

Comment: How it's work with Ajax?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid, please can you look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164905/submit-form-jquery